# Setting the trigger to call in 5 minutes after the start, and then every day at 10:00

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, quartz.net

Hello It is necessary for the rules to interrogate web server.

Regulation is that every day at 10:00 and 1 time after 5 minutes immediately after the start of the program.

Configure the call trigger at 10:00 I was able to

```
  ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
        .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(10, 00))
        .ForJob(job)
        .Build();
```

But how to add 1 drawdown once after 5 minutes after the start?

```
 scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more simple trigger. Schedule that one at the specific moment with no repetition. There you are with the example. More information you can find at [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html).

```
// trigger builder creates simple trigger by default, actually an ITrigger is returned 
ISimpleTrigger trigger = (ISimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder
.Create()
.WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
.StartAt(myStartTime) // some Date
.ForJob("job1", "group1") // identify job with name, group strings
.Build();
```

Comment: I add two trigers. Thanks